# Skaffold not trigger without file closing on Windows OS

Tags: skaffold

In my opinions, `skaffold` should be triggered when I save the file. I shouldn't need to close the file. Am I right?

#### Information

- Skaffold version: v1.39.2
- Operating system: Windows 10 Enterprise 2009 10.0.19041.1566

I'm using the [examples/jib-sync](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/tree/main/examples/jib-sync). I am making changes to the `src\main\java\hello\HelloController.java` file with `vim`. When I save the file with `:w` command, I get the following log:

```
skaffold dev -f skaffold-gradle.yml -v trace
```

```
[...]
[...]
time="2022-08-24T01:20:10+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Rename: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java~\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:10+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Rename: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:10+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Create: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:10+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:10+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Remove: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java~\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:11+03:00" level=debug msg="Using wrapper gradlew.bat for gradle" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:11+03:00" level=debug msg="Found dependencies for jib-gradle artifact: [build.gradle src\\main\\java\\hello\\Application.java src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java.swp src\\main\\jib\\direct-file]" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:11+03:00" level=info msg="files modified: [src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java.swp]" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:11+03:00" level=debug msg="Using wrapper gradlew.bat for gradle" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:11+03:00" level=debug msg="Running command: [cmd /c C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\gradlew.bat --console=plain _skaffoldFailIfJibOutOfDate -Djib.requiredVersion=2.0.0 :_jibSkaffoldSyncMap -x test -Psync -Djib.to.auth.username=admin -Djib.to.auth.password=admin]" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:13+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\fileHashes\\fileHashes.lock\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:13+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\buildOutputCleanup\\buildOutputCleanup.lock\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:13+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\fileContent\\fileContent.lock\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:13+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\executionHistory\\executionHistory.lock\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\javaCompile\\javaCompile.lock\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\javaCompile\\classAnalysis.bin\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Remove: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\build\\classes\\java\\main\\hello\\HelloController.class\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Create: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\build\\classes\\java\\main\\hello\\HelloController.class\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\build\\classes\\java\\main\\hello\\HelloController.class\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\fileChanges\\last-build.bin\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\fileChanges\\last-build.bin\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\fileContent\\fileContent.lock\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\buildOutputCleanup\\buildOutputCleanup.lock\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\executionHistory\\executionHistory.lock\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\javaCompile\\javaCompile.lock\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Change detectednotify.Write: \"C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\.gradle\\5.6.4\\fileHashes\\fileHashes.lock\"" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Command output: [> Task :_skaffoldFailIfJibOutOfDate\r\n> Task :compileJava\r\n> Task :processResources NO-SOURCE\r\n> Task :classes\r\n\r\n> Task :_jibSkaffoldSyncMap\r\n\r\nBEGIN JIB JSON: SYNCMAP/1\r\n{\"generated\":[{\"src\":\"C:\\\\repos\\\\drafts\\\\skaffold\\\\examples\\\\jib-sync\\\\build\\\\classes\\\\java\\\\main\\\\hello\\\\Application.class\",\"dest\":\"/app/classes/hello/Application.class\"},{\"src\":\"C:\\\\repos\\\\drafts\\\\skaffold\\\\examples\\\\jib-sync\\\\build\\\\classes\\\\java\\\\main\\\\hello\\\\HelloController.class\",\"dest\":\"/app/classes/hello/HelloController.class\"}],\"direct\":[{\"src\":\"C:\\\\repos\\\\drafts\\\\skaffold\\\\examples\\\\jib-sync\\\\src\\\\main\\\\jib\\\\direct-file\",\"dest\":\"/direct-file\"}]}\r\n\r\nBUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s\r\n3 actionable tasks: 3 executed\r\n]" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=trace msg="dev intents: build true, sync true, deploy true\n" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg=" devloop: build false, sync true, deploy false\n" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
Syncing 1 files for my-private-registry.local/test-file-sync:2022-08-24_01-15-41.656@sha256:290c18d2c5324f36ed7ed5950ca6eb4ad582d852bb27c1575a60ca95e1082e48
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=info msg="Copying files:map[C:\\repos\\drafts\\skaffold\\examples\\jib-sync\\build\\classes\\java\\main\\hello\\HelloController.class:[/app/classes/hello/HelloController.class]]tomy-private-registry.local/test-file-sync:2022-08-24_01-15-41.656@sha256:290c18d2c5324f36ed7ed5950ca6eb4ad582d852bb27c1575a60ca95e1082e48" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="getting client config for kubeContext: `kind-kind`" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:14+03:00" level=debug msg="Running command: [kubectl --context kind-kind exec test-file-sync --namespace default -c test-file-sync -i -- tar xmf - -C / --no-same-owner]" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
Watching for changes...
time="2022-08-24T01:20:15+03:00" level=debug msg="Using wrapper gradlew.bat for gradle" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:15+03:00" level=debug msg="Found dependencies for jib-gradle artifact: [build.gradle src\\main\\java\\hello\\Application.java src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java src\\main\\java\\hello\\HelloController.java.swp src\\main\\jib\\direct-file]" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
time="2022-08-24T01:20:15+03:00" level=trace msg="dev intents: build true, sync true, deploy true\n" subtask=-1 task=DevLoop
```

As a result, the pod and container image are not recreated. By the way, when I make changes in VSCode, I get the above result.

When I make changes in the same file with `vim`, `save+quit` it with `:wq` command, the pod and container image are recreated. So, I can see the difference in the changes I made with curl.

Do I have to save+quit the file each time to recreate the pod with the changes?

### Update: 24 Aug 2022

I tried the case I mentioned above on a Linux computer. There is no need to `save+quit` here. When I applied the `:w` command from `vim`, the pod and container image was created again. I want this to work on Windows OS as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim creates a swap file for each file being edited, which is normally placed alongside the file but named `.<file>.swp`.  Skaffold doesn't know that these swap files are transient files that should be ignored.  When Skaffold detects a change to a file that isn't matched by any sync rules, like a `.swp` file, then Skaffold causes the image to be rebuilt.

You can configure Vim to create its temp files outside of the local directory by adding something like the following to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
" put .swp and backups outside of the directory to avoid triggering file watchers
set directory=$HOME/.vim/swapfiles//
set backupdir=$HOME/.vim/backups//
set undodir=$HOME/.vim/undos//
```

All that said, your log is puzzling as it shows a change to a `HelloController.java.swp` file, but it is not triggering a rebuild.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian de Alwis for the detailed explanation, I understand super well.

I don't use vim under normal conditions, I wrote vim as an example. When I edit the relevant file in `VS Code` or `Intellij Idea` editors, the container image and pod are **not** recreated. When I edit with any editor and save the relevant file, I want the container image and the pod to be recreated. What can I do in this situation?

Comment: Oh! My apologies: I completely misunderstood. If you want to rebuild the image, disable sync mode change the `sync.auto: false` in your `skaffold.yaml`. You shouldn’t need to disable this if using Spring Boot Dev Tools, which detects class file change on disk and triggers a Ramos reload. But other frameworks may not support this reload.

Comment: You are awesome! My needs were met exactly. I'm so grateful.